# FIXML python parser

Tags: python, xml, parsing, pandas, fix-protocol

I am looking to parse a FIXML file (~150M size) in python and eventually generate a pandas dataframe off the parsed data. I have been experimenting with xmltodict & the ETree parsers for xml but wondering if there is already a python parser for 'FIXML' that could be easier to use in order to generate a pandas dataframe.

Anyone knows?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The PyPI package index shows several hits for FIXML parsers:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=fixml&submit=search

That said, the schema is simple so using *lxml* is also a reasonable choice.